# Android-Buffering values to minimize the number of disk writes?

Tags: android, buffer, text-files

In my `Android application` I am reading brain data values from an `EEG headset`. These values are then being written to a `Text File.`

The problem with this is that the values are being produced **500 times a seconds.** As a result they are also being written to the text file 500 times a second, which I don't want.

I only want the values to be displayed in the text file once a second. I was reading about [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) to do so.

How could I use buffering in my case to solve the problem?

Below is my current android code, and also rough pseudo code for what i'm trying to achieve.

**Current Android code:**

**Method used to save the data to file:**

```
public void writeToFileRawData(String data) {

        // creating the file where the contents will be written to
        File file = new File(dir, fileNameRaw + ".txt");

        FileOutputStream os;

        try {

            boolean append = true;

            os = new FileOutputStream(file, append);

            String writeMe = data + "\n";

            os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Calling the above method within the handler for the Headset Values:**

Note: in code below "order" is irrelevant, it is just a method used for formatting the txt.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:

                // creating the string to be written to file
                String line2 = order(seconds2 + "") + order("" + msg.arg1)
                        + "\n";

                // write the string to file
                writeToFileRawData(line2);

                break;
```

**Rough Pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve:**

```
brainWaveRaw

time    voltage
xxx     yyyy
xxx     yyyy

[and there should be 500 of these per second]
(buffer these to minimize number of disk writes)

// initialize
timeOfLastRawWrite = timeNow
rawWriteStringBuffer = ''


rawEvent(raw (list of last one or few raw samples))
        eventTime = timeNow
        for every entry r in raw
                rawWriteStringBuffer.append(printf("%d %d\n", eventTime, r))
        if timeNow-timeOfLastRawWrite > one second
        write rawWriteStringBuffer to file
        rawWriteStringBuffer = ''
        timeOfLastRawWrite = timeNow



// e.g. if last set of raw values was [123, 456, 678], arrived at time
9876

9876 123
9876 456
9876 678
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't open the file every time.
2. Use [BufferedOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html).
3. You might want to flush the stream every several times.

   ```
   Handler mHandler; // member of your Activity class

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       final String dir = ...;
       final String fileNameRaw = ...;

       mHandler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               // msg.what determines the type of each message

               switch (msg.what) {
               case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:

                   // creating the string to be written to file
                   String line2 = order(seconds2 + "") + order("" + msg.arg1)
                           + "\n";

                   // write the string to file
                   writeToFileRawData(line2);

                   break;
               }          
           }

           // members of your custom Handler class
           private File mFile = new File(dir, fileNameRaw + ".txt");
           private BufferedOutputStream mOs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mFile, true));
           private  int mWriteCnt = 0;

           // moved this function from Activity to your custom Handler class as well
           private void writeToFileRawData(String data) {
               try {
                   mOs.write(data.getBytes());
                   mOs.write("\n".getBytes());
                   if (++mWriteCnt == 500) {
                       mOs.flush();
                       mWriteCnt = 0;
                   }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, so I should place these variable declarations in the onCreate Method? Then put change writeToFileRawData as shown above?

Comment: if this is the case, how would I alter the code related to the handler? (seond code block)

Comment: Variables should be class members, as I wrote in my answer. Initialization probably should be performed in onCreate, if `YourClass` is an Activity, which is not obvious from your question. Then in `handleMessage()` you just call `writeToFileRawData(data2)` as you're doing now.

Comment: In fact all the code can be put into the Handler, check updated answer.

Comment: Yes my class is an activity thanks! Can you please edit the code to show the oncreate method, the writeToFileRawData method and also what I should do in the TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA: of the handler! I can then accept the answer!

Comment: Can I not have the writeToFileRawData  method outside the handler then call it within it?

Comment: Thanks, but it isnt clear what I should do inside TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA and also where: private File mFile = new File(dir, fileNameRaw + ".txt");
        private BufferedOutputStream mOs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mFile, true));
        private  int mWriteCnt = 0;
 should be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59811/discussion-between-anton-savin-and-codeme2020).